# Why do I keep on getting GET request error from GitHub API

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I'm trying to learn the requests library in python and I'm following a guide. I'm sending a get request to api.github.com/user but I keep on getting a Status Code of 401. For username, I was using my email at first, but I thought that was what was making it fail so I changed it to my GitHub username and it still doesn't work. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or are there solutions?

```
import requests
from getpass import getpass

response = requests.get(
    "https://api.github.com/user",
    auth=('username', getpass())
)
print(response)
```

Comment: You must authenticate before you can request a user https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer authenticate to the GitHub API using Basic authentication (a username and password).  That ability has been removed.  This API endpoint requires authentication because it tells you the current user, and when you're not logged in, there is no current user.

You'll need to generate a personal access token with the appropriate scopes and [use it to authenticate to the API instead](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#authentication).  You can also use an OAuth token if you're using an OAuth app, but it doesn't sound like you need that in this case.